# error position must be between 0 and n in function that filters and sums by date ranges

Tags: r, dplyr

For the following sample dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)
Sessions <- ceiling(rnorm(50, mean = 3000, sd = 300))
Registrations <- ceiling(rnorm(50, mean = 800, sd = 100))
Conversions <- ceiling(rnorm(50, mean = 400, sd = 50))
Date_Range = seq(Sys.Date() - 50, Sys.Date() - 1, by = 1)
sample_data <- data.frame(Date_Range,Sessions, Registrations, Conversions)
sample_data <- tbl_df(sample_data)
```

I have the following function which is meant to provide sum total of a given metric for a date range:

```
sumByDates <- function(startDate, endDate, metric) {
    sum(filter(sample_data, Date_Range >= startDate & Date_Range <= endDate) %>% select(metric))
}
```

Now if I do this:

```
sumByDates(Sys.Date()-5, Sys.Date()-1, Sessions)
```

I would get:

```
Error: Position must be between 0 and n
Called from: combine_vars(vars, ind_list)
Browse[1]> Q
```

How can I sum a given metric in `sample_data` for a given `Date_Range`?

Answer (score 0):

Changed `select(metric)` to `select_(metric)` and made metric a string when calling the function `sumByDates(Sys.Date()-5, Sys.Date()-1, "Sessions")`.

As per "Non Standard Evaluations" in DPLYR